# jquery .datepicker is not a function (although I know it is)

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm having a real problem tracking down why i'm getting the error "$("#checkIn").datepicker is not a function" on the link below. You should see the jquery ui calendar when you click either of the input's, or the calendar buttons.

I can see in the net panel of firebug that everything's loaded correctly so i'm not sure what the deal is.

--link removed--

Comment: I see two separate jQuery includes on that page but zero jQuery-UI JavaScript includes.

Comment: If you uncomment the Google CDN's jQueryUI script reference does it work?

Comment: The jquery ui file is in there. look again. It's in the middle or so.

Comment: If I uncomment Google's CDN jqueryUI it still does not work.

Comment: Try including Jquery-ui script after jquery-min script. (change the order).

Comment: The jquery-ui script is after the jquery script. The jquery script is jquery-min.js and the jqueryUI script is jquery-ui-calendar.js

Comment: You should only be loading jQuery itself once.  You are including both 1.5 and 1.6 versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change $('#checkIn').datepicker() to jQuery('#checkIn').datepicker()

Comment: If you run this in firebug on your site it will instantiate without errors... also may want to change this for any event called by those datepicker instances - like $('#checkOut').datepicker("show"); and any other instances where you want to apply datepicker.

Comment: That's works! I'm guessing the duplicate jquery declaration's throws it off, but this fixes it. It's not my wordpress site and I can't figure out where one of those jquery declarations is coming from. Probably a plugin or something.

Comment: jQuery() is what $ is referencing. True, it may be an old version you're calling or the fact that you have 2 versions being called - but either way, jQuery() is the safe way to do it no matter what version you're using. Sometimes this same error can surface if there is some minute js syntax error as well, though that is more likely to be picked up in firebug.

Answer (score 1):

You're running an old version of jQuery with a much newer version of jQueryUI. May or may not solve your problem but I'd suggest fixing that first.

Comment: jqueryUI is stable with jquery.1.3.2 and up. It's on the jqueryUI website.